# Angular 5: HttpParams Send Integer Instead Of String Value?

Tags: angular

This works fine as long as the db column subCatId requires a varchar string.

```
this.params = {
   'filter': `(${column} like ${subCatId}%)`
}
```

It fails when the column requires an integer, probably due to the back ticks turning the whole URL params into a string.

I've been trying variations of this but none have worked.  They won't compile.

```
'filter': `${column}%3D`${subCatId}
or
'filter': `${column}=`${subCatId}
```

This does work, generated with Swagger:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/v2/pfpsql/_table/skills?
   fields=skill_id%2C%20skill_name%2C%20category_id&filter=category_id%20%3D%202
```

So the Swagger example doesn't create a problem with the table column integer constraint.  The Angular code does.  The "2" at the end of the string is the problem in Angular HttpParams.  Fields work fine.

Any thoughts how to do this?  Probably simple but I'm new to this topic and couldn't find advice online with many searches.

Comment: Can you include some examples of what the URL looks like for the cases where you say it doesn't work? Anything after the `?` is called the query-*string*, so the whole thing is a string (yeah, it rhymes), even in your Swagger example.

Comment: Here is one permeation:  http://localhost:8080/api/v2/pfpsql/_table/skills?filter=category_id&ids=2.   The result is only the first record in the table and no relation to the category_id.  I should mention that the compile problem is to the right of the category_id in the Angular versions above.  The fields work well. That "2" at the end is the issue.  I'll add this comment to the main post.

Comment: Why does your first example end with a `%`? I'm going to guess it was for a `LIKE '%'` style query, but of course that won't work if the column requires an integer. I can't see exactly what you are trying to achieve, as your "bad" example differs from the first code snippet's structure. As an aside, this looks like it's at risk of [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks...

Comment: Yes, it was 'like'.  I just changed it in my post.  That was the setup that worked -- until I changed the column from string to integer because it seems like numeric id's should be integers.  This is for dev purposes.  I'll send params to the server for queries when I get to the backend coding.

Comment: For the two lines that don't compile, just move the 2nd ` to the end of the line and see if that does what you need it to.

Comment: Got it, it works now.  So the problem wasn't the back ticks converting a number to a string but the LIKE query.  Thanks!  That insight helps a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference this is the whole http call.  Many thanks to Kirk Larkin!  See the comments with the OP for background.

```
public getSubCatTags(dbTable, column, subCatId):  Observable<any>  {
this.params = {
      'fields': `skill_id, skill_name, category_id`,
      'filter': `${column} = ${subCatId}`
    };
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseUrl}${dbTable}`, {params: this.params, headers: this.headers});
  }
```